# Old TV series with a time-travelling boy and girl and a mechanical time guardian

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, tv

There was a boy and a girl, and they were doing time traveling. Mechanic person guarding a big clock, his hands like clock hands. Like some time guardian.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you see this?  Where?  Was it animated or live-action?  Black-and-white or in colour?  How old were the boy and girl?  What kind of clothing did they wear?  Why were they time-travelling?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flying_House_(TV_series) ?

Comment: It looks like [Timeslip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeslip) has a time traveling boy and girl, but I cant find a mention of a clock.  Looks interesting though.

Comment: My first thought from the title was *Jack Kirby... Time Warrior!*, but no clock hands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Finders Keepers](https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/23773/finders-keepers), [Australian TV](https://dbpedia.org/page/Finders_Keepers_(Australian_TV_series)), 1991?

> Finders Keepers, also known as The Finder, is an Australian children's
> television show, directed by Scott Hicks, that first aired on 28
> October 1991, based on a book by Emily Rodda. The story revolves
> around a boy called Patrick who, whilst playing on a computer,
> receives an invitation to take part on a TV game show called "Finders
> Keepers" through a store in a shopping arcade. He accepts the
> invitation and is sucked into another world where he is given clues to
> find missing treasures from his own world and take part in an
> interdimensional hunt.

Your 'Mechanic person' may be the creepy Clock Robot:

[image: Clock Robot]

There are episodes on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3Mnh_eJ54M&t=18s).

Comment: Oh, yes. Finders Keepers, 1991. Pretty old, but I can remember the Clock Robot now. Thank s lot! COuldnt remember for weeks, so I had to ask online on several websites. Cool, thanks again.

Comment: some people were writing theyve been searching for the show for 10 and some for 20years. Ive found it in 10days thanks to you. Thank you :)